# How to get DefaultUrl annotation?

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

I use serenity bdd and have such class

```
@DefaultUrl("http://www.google.com")
public class SamplePage extends PageObject {
}
```

Now I can open google-page with this code:

```
public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        actor.attemptsTo(
                Open.browserOn().the(SamplePage)        
        );
 }
```

But after this I need to check if URL use http or https.
So, how can I get value from @DefaultUrl annotation?

Answer (score 0):

```
SamplePage.getClass().getAnnotation(DefaultUrl.class).value()
```

Comment: [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.thucydides/thucydides-core/0.9.275/net/thucydides/core/annotations/DefaultUrl.java#DefaultUrl)